# Export to pdf in MVC 4(Embed Html in pdf)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, itext

I am  trying to export pdf using MVC 4. While exporting when trying to embed Html in pdf document error occur:

- The type or namespace name 'tool' does not exist in the namespace
  'iTextSharp'

I have added  iTextSharp.dll but i dont know why i am getting error. Please help me thanks in advance.

below is my method:

```
  public FileResult ExportData()
    {
        List<Tb_ModalListFileUpload> objlist = new List<Tb_ModalListFileUpload>();

        objlist = (from p in obj.Tb_ModalListFileUpload select p).ToList();

        WebGrid wd = new WebGrid(source: objlist, canPage: false, canSort: false);

        string griddata = wd.GetHtml(
        columns: wd.Columns
        (
        wd.Column(columnName: "SRNO", header: "SRNO"),
        wd.Column(columnName: "ModelName", header: "Model Name"),
        wd.Column(columnName: "ModelCC", header: "Model CC"),

        wd.Column(columnName: "ModelRate", header: "Model Rate"),
        wd.Column(columnName: "ModelRC", header: "Model RC"),
        wd.Column(columnName: "IncWith0", header: "Inc With 0"),
        wd.Column(columnName: "IncWith50", header: "Inc With 50"),
        wd.Column(columnName: "Provisional", header: "Provisional"),
        wd.Column(columnName: "NetPriceWith0", header: "Net Price With 0"),
        wd.Column(columnName: "NetPriceWith50", header: "Net Price With 50")

        )
        ).ToString();

        string exportData = String.Format("<html><head>{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>", "<style>table{ border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: separate; }</style>", griddata);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();

            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to iTextSharp's primary DLL you also need to add the separate but related [`XMLWorker`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/) for HTML processing.

Comment: I have added these files but still error occurring. I dont know whats going wrong. Please help me if u have more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Late comment, but perhaps it helps someone else.

Its not available with that package , try to download it separately. I have used the following link [Download here](http://en.osdn.jp/projects/sfnet_itextsharp/downloads/xmlworker/xmlworker-5.5.4/itextsharp.xmlworker-all-5.5.4.zip/)

I had the same issue and this sorted it out. Remember to reference the DLL after its downloaded/extracted.